# Java How do I pass interface as parameter in Constructor?

Tags: java, gwt

I am creating a Composite widgets that have been used in GWT Showcase.

```
new DialogBoxWidget(constants);
```

//Here I am stucked with error : The constructor DialogBoxWidget(ShowcaseConstants) is undefined.

```
/**
* Constants used throughout the showcase.
*/
public interface ShowcaseConstants extends MenuConstants,       
CwDialogBox.CwConstants{
     /**
      * The path to source code for examples, raw files, and style definitions.
      */
  String DST_SOURCE = "gwtShowcaseSource/";
}
```

Here is my DialogBoxWidget.java that is Composite

```
 @ShowcaseSource
public static interface CwConstants extends Constants {
    String cwDialogBoxCaption();

    String cwDialogBoxClose();

    String cwDialogBoxDescription();

    String cwDialogBoxDetails();

    String cwDialogBoxItem();

    String cwDialogBoxListBoxInfo();

    String cwDialogBoxMakeTransparent();

    String cwDialogBoxName();

    String cwDialogBoxShowButton();
}

/**
 * An instance of the constants.
 */
@ShowcaseData
private final CwConstants constants;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * @param constants2 
 *
 * @param constants the constants
 */
public DialogBoxWidget(CwConstants constants) {

    // Add a hyper link to each section in the Widgets category
    ShowcaseConstants allConstants = GWT.create(ShowcaseConstants.class);
    this.constants = constants;
    // Create the dialog box
    final DialogBox dialogBox = createDialogBox();
    dialogBox.setGlassEnabled(true);
    dialogBox.setAnimationEnabled(true);

    // Create a button to show the dialog Box
    Button openButton = new Button(
            allConstants.cwDialogBoxShowButton(), new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent sender) {
                    dialogBox.center();
                    dialogBox.show();
                }
            });

    // Create a ListBox
    HTML listDesc = new HTML(
            "<br><br><br>" + allConstants.cwDialogBoxListBoxInfo());

    ListBox list = new ListBox();
    list.setVisibleItemCount(1);
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        list.addItem(allConstants.cwDialogBoxItem() + " " + i);
    }

    // Add the button and list to a panel
    VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    vPanel.setSpacing(8);
    vPanel.add(openButton);
    vPanel.add(listDesc);
    vPanel.add(list);
    initWidget(vPanel);
}
```

Below is the code of onModuleLoad()

```
ShowcaseConstants constants = GWT.create(ShowcaseConstants.class);
 @ShowcaseSource
public void onModuleLoad() {

    DialogBoxWidget dialogBox = new DialogBoxWidget(constants);//Here I am stucked with error : The constructor DialogBoxWidget(ShowcaseConstants) is undefined
    //Add it to the RootPanel.
    RootPanel.get().add(dialogBox);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your constructor to

```
public DialogBoxWidget(ShowcaseConstants  constants) {
```

You construtor accepting  `CwConstants`

```
public DialogBoxWidget(CwConstants constants) {
```

and you are trying to pass `ShowcaseConstants`

or create

```
CwConstants constants = GWT.create(CwConstants.class);
```

and pass this.

Comment: Yes that is one solution ,But I want to use CwConstants.So that I don't have to make more changes in the code.

Comment: They have used "new CwDialogBox(constants)" to initialize the dialog box. I want to use it the same way.

Comment: So you  create `CwConstants constants = GWT.create(CwConstants.class);`  and pass this constants.

Comment: Yes your answer is totally acceptable,but why their code does not give any error .I feel there is something which I am not understanding. I want to know that

Comment: It's impossible to explain you without seeing their code.Please paste there code or I am guessing ,They are also passing the same or they are pointing to another constructor which accepts their Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet you get your refactoring/copy-paste wrong: `ShowcaseConstants` extends `CwDialogBox.CwConstants` instead of `DialogBoxWidget.CwConstants`.